# Modelo validar mostrar notificación

Tags: java, spring

Estoy tratando de hacer una notificación pero sin parámetros. ¿Cómo hago para traer la notificación?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "eliminar_dependencia.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView EliminarDependencia(HttpServletRequest re) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();

    try {
        new MetodosHql().eliminarDatos(Integer.parseInt(re.getParameter("id")), new Dependencias());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("jose"+e);   
    }  
    if (new validar_session().valido_session(re) == true) {
        mav.setViewName("redirect:/admin_roles.htm");
    } else {
        mav.setViewName("redirect:/login.htm");
    }
    return mav;
}
public class ValidarDependenciaCheckbox implements Validator {

    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
    }
    public void validate(Object o, Errors errors) {
        System.out.println("LLEGUE");
        errors.reject("error");
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Dónde estás tratando de hacer la notificación? ¿Qué quieres notificar? ¿A dónde quieres enviar esa notificación?

Comment: estoy tratando la notificacion en el validardependenciacheckbox, lo que quero notificar es que no se puede eliminar,  quiero envairla a la vista